# Define data.frame with 0 rows but >0 columns

Tags: r

I want to pass a predefined but empty `data.frame` to shiny/DT. Are there good practices?

What I found out is that

```
x <- data.frame(a=NA, b=NA)[!is.na(x$a),]
str(x)
```

produces the desired result.

```
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: logi 
 $ b: logi
```

But it looks clumsy. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: `data.frame(a=NA,b=NA)[0,]`? BTW, your `[!is.na(x$a),]` pre-supposes that you created `x <- data.frame(..)` and after that assignment, the next expression references that. In other words, `x` does not exist in your expression above when that `[..]` is evaluated.

Comment: So why does it work?

Comment: Eval `rm(x)`, then run `x <- data.frame(a=NA, b=NA)[!is.na(x$a),]` again, you should receive the error `object 'x' not found`.